# tikzDevice in R, set absolutlely all fonts, fontsizes and fontweights to TeX document fontsize

Tags: tikz-pgf, r, tikzdevice

I am learning R, and I want to use tikz to inlcude R plots in my documents. However, to me, half the point is that I want to set absolutely all typefaces, fontsizes, fontweights to the TeX-document font body. I looked up the documentation of tikzDevice and par(), however I wasn't able to find a way to do this. Please see the attached documents to see what I mean:

```
\documentclass[11pt,norsk,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[norsk]{babel}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, top=1in,bottom=1.1in,right=0.9in,left=0.9in]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{pgf, pgfplots}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\date{\normalsize \today}
\begin{document}
I want all fonts in R plots to be exactly like this one.
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
  \begin{center}
    \input{fig1.tex}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

And the R-script generatic fig1.tex:

```
library(tikzDevice)
tikz("/home/marius/Dokumenter/stk1110/oblig2/fig1.tex", width = 6, height = 5, pointsize=11)

# some data
menn = c(36.1,36.3,36.4,36.6,36.6,36.7,36.7,37.0,36.5,37.1)  
kvinner = c(36.6,36.7,36.8,36.8,36.7,37.0,37.1,37.3,36.9,37.4)

par(mfrow=c(2,3))

# first row
boxplot(menn)
qqnorm(menn)
qqline(menn)
hist(menn, freq=FALSE)
x = seq(36,37.4,0.01)
lines(x, 1/(2*pi*var(menn))^0.5*exp(-(x-mean(menn))^2/(2*var(menn))))

# second row
boxplot(kvinner)
qqnorm(kvinner)
qqline(kvinner)
hist(kvinner, freq=FALSE)
lines(x, 1/(2*pi*var(kvinner))^0.5*exp(-(x-mean(kvinner))^2/(2*var(kvinner))))

par(ps=1, cex=1, cex.main=111, cex.lab=111, cex.axis=111, cex.sub=111, font.main=1)
dev.off()
```

I'd like this to work for the majority of different plots, if not all, so that I can have exactly the same font as my document body. Even for figure titles. Are you able to suggest an solution?

Comment: Maybe a workaround would be to compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, using a font that would be recognized by cairo under R?

Comment: This question has also been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73503180/3193733

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In one word: [knitr](https://yihui.name/knitr).

In more words: Save it as example.Rnw and compite and edit With Rstudio, then use the "Compile PDF" button.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper, top=1in,bottom=1.1in,right=0.9in,left=0.9in]{geometry}
\begin{document}
I want all fonts in R plots to be exactly like this one.

<<dev="tikz", echo=F, fig.cap="A tikz plot",  fig.width=6, fig.height=5>>=
# par(ps=1, cex=1, cex.main=111, cex.lab=111, cex.axis=111, cex.sub=111, font.main=1)
# some data
menn = c(36.1,36.3,36.4,36.6,36.6,36.7,36.7,37.0,36.5,37.1)  
kvinner = c(36.6,36.7,36.8,36.8,36.7,37.0,37.1,37.3,36.9,37.4)
par(mfrow=c(2,3))
# first row
boxplot(menn)
qqnorm(menn)
qqline(menn)
hist(menn, freq=FALSE)
x = seq(36,37.4,0.01)
lines(x, 1/(2*pi*var(menn))^0.5*exp(-(x-mean(menn))^2/(2*var(menn))))
# second row
boxplot(kvinner)
qqnorm(kvinner)
qqline(kvinner)
hist(kvinner, freq=FALSE)
lines(x, 1/(2*pi*var(kvinner))^0.5*exp(-(x-mean(kvinner))^2/(2*var(kvinner))))
@
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]